# Positive lookahead not working as expected

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following regex with a positive lookahead:

```
/black(?=hand)[ s]/
```

I want it to match **blackhands** or **blackhand**. However, it doesn't match anything. I am testing on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually want to match the space following "blackhand", or do you want to ensure that there are no letters other than "s" following it? If you want to match either "s" or the end of the word, you can use `(?:s|\b)` instead of `[ s]`, where `\b` matches a word boundary (either the beginning or end of a word). Then it will match "blackhand" when it is at the end of the string (followed by nothing), at the end of a sentence (followed by a period), at the end of a line (followed by a newline), at the end of a clause (followed by a comma), or followed by any other punctuation.

Comment: Assertions just _look_ in a certain direction for characters, they don't move the current match position. So if you look forward for `hello` then try to match `goodbye`, it never matches. Fwiw `/blackhands?/` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank both of you ;) you cleared good things

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lookahead does not consume the string being searched. That means that the `[ s]` is trying to match a space or **s** immediately following **black**. However, your lookahead says that **hand** must follow **black**, so the regular expression can never match anything.

To match either **blackhands** or **blackhand**  while using lookahead, move `[ s]` within the lookahead: `black(?=hand[ s])`. Alternatively, don't use lookahead at all: `blackhand[ s]`.

Answer (score 3):

You regex isn't matching `blackhands` or `blackhands` because it is trying to match a space or letter `s` (character class `[ s]`) right after text `black` and also looking ahead `hand` after `black`.

To match both inputs you will need this lookahead:

```
/black(?=hands?)/
```

Or just don't use any lookahead and use:

```
/blackhands?/
```

#### [Good reference on lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1):

In short, you should use

```
/\bblackhands?\b/
```

Now, your regex is a bit too complex for this task. It consists of

- `black` - matching `black` literally
- `(?=hand)` - a positive lookahead that **requires** `hand` to appear right after `black` - **but does not consume characters, engine stays at the same position in string!**
- `[ s]` - a character class matching either a space or a `s` - **obligatorily right after the `black`**.

**So, you will never get your matches, because a space or `s` do not appear in the first position of `hand` (it is `h`).**

This is [how lookarounds work](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> The difference is that lookaround actually matches characters, but then **gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match**. That is why they are called *"assertions"*. They do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.

**In your case, it is not necessary.** 
Just use `\b` - a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) - to match whole words `blackhand` or `blackhands`.