# Why do I have to add `.{8}` to my look-ahead based regex in order to match passwords?

Tags: regex

I am using the following regular expression to confirm:

- 2 letters in upper-case
- 1 special character (in `!@#$&*`)
- 2 numerals (`0`–`9`)
- 3 letters in lower-case

```regex
^(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{8}$
```

And it works fine for the flowing password: `AdiNm!15` but I don’t understand why I had to write `.{8}`. If I removed `.{8}` it is not working. But I don’t like to add restriction of string length. Any Idea?

Comment: Replace `{8}` with `*` (to match 0 or more chars) or `+` (to match 1 or more)

Comment: That's a very odd dupe. I think the question is more about understanding the `$` anchor. *That's* the reason why you need the `.{8}` or `.*` or `.+`, because it matches at the end of the string.

Comment: The core misunderstanding comes from the look-aheads `(?=`…`)`. They are zero-width assertions, meaning, they don’t consume characters. If you reduce your regex without the `.{8}` to only actually consumed characters, it would just be `^$`, which matches only empty strings. Since this contradicts any look-ahead assertions, the regex never matches anything. A more fitting dupe target is [Positive lookahead not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31347686/4642212).

Comment: You should read [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922)