# Understanding positive lookaheads and backtracking in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, positive-lookahead

I can't completely wrap my head around combining positive lookaheads and backtracking in JavaScript. I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47121091/1836143), as well as this [article](http://rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) and did some testing with https://regex101.com/, but don't quite get the result I'm expecting.

So given the test string *banana12*, the following works:

- `(?=\d{2,})` - assert that the string contains at least two digits
- `(?=[a-z]{5,})` - assert that the string contains at least five lowercase characters

These two conditions work for both *banana12* and *12banana*.

However, when I try to combine the two `(?=\d{2,})(?=[a-z]{5,})`, I don't get a match. In order to get a match when using *banana12*, I need to add `\D*` to the digit-testing lookahead: `(?=\D*\d{2,})(?=[a-z]{5,})`.

Why doesn't `(?=\d{2,})(?=[a-z]{5,})` work?

If I change the test string to *12banan*, to get a match I need to use: `(?=\d{2,})(?=[^a-z]*[a-z]{5,})` - so this time no backtracking for the digits, backtracking for the lowercase letters.

So in general, if I want to make sure, that my regex matches correctly both strings (*12banana*, *banana12*), I need to use: `(?=\D*\d{2,})(?=[^a-z]*[a-z]{5,})`.

Why? If both lookaheads work on their own, why don't they work in combination and why is it necessary to add backtracking?

Comment: `(?=\d{2,})(?=[a-z]{5,})` tries to match the POSITION which is IMMEDIATELY followed by 2 or more digits AND 5 or more letters. That is never possible

Comment: `(?=\d{2,})(?=[a-z]{5,})` require the text immediately to the right to match both patterns at the same time

Comment: Actually, it is not that complicated. Lookarounds ensure a position and when you add multiple lookarounds the assertion must be true for all of them for this specific position. You can see it on https://regex101.com/r/QCmxts/1 and https://regex101.com/r/QCmxts/2 respectively - the positions differ.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973609/3832970 does explain it to you. *Lookarounds are zero width assertions. They check for a regex (towards right or left of the current position - based on ahead or behind), succeeds or fails when a match is found (based on if it is positive or negative) and discards the matched portion. **They don't consume any character - the matching for regex following them (if any), will start at the same cursor position**.*

Comment: Nobody said the real reason: They do NOT consume characters.

Comment: WiktorStribiżew, ibrahim-tanyalcin -> I already knew that lookaheads don't consume characters and https://regex101.com/ visualizes this in a great way. However, this didn't help me to understand why the combination doesn't work - my logic was - since they don't consume characters, then the two should work in combination, because each one starts at the beginning. What I wasn't realizing was that there must be a position, which satisfies both conditions. In that sense, no, @WiktorStribiżew, the question/answer you pointed to, didn't help me (but your comment did).

Comment: I added [another link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31347783/3832970), it explains that in depth.